# why is my site changing ie9 document Mode

Tags: internet-explorer-9

My website has the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I'm noticing that ie9 is changing the document mode on various pages.

1. am i able to get information on what is causing the mode to change?
2. on one page it changed to ie7 and the images display. When i change it back to ie9 mode the images doesn't display. What would are some of the causes of this issue.

I appreciate i could add the following. But i'd rather get the root causes.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Is this page actually on the internet or are you testing it locally?  To answer (2) I would have to see the code I reckon.